# Is it possible to embed certain custom profile fields as a block in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Is there a Drupal module that will let a user edit some profile fields or a field collection on a specific page. For example, assume I have a page that talks about the benefits of different levels of college degree and a Field collection that captures degree level and school name. I would like to have those profile fields editable on that page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean profile2, you can write a custom module containing a block, a good example of a custom blok is included on https://drupal.org/project/examples.

Then you can use hook_form_profile2_form_alter to call the individual fields making up your form.